# What does " /bin/sh <$(tty) >$(tty) 2>$(tty) " mean?

Tags: linux, redirection, pipe, privileges, at

I was looking at the [GTFOBINS](https://gtfobins.github.io/gtfobins/at/#sudo) page for the at command and saw this command (last command in that page)

```
echo "/bin/sh <$(tty) >$(tty) 2>$(tty)" | sudo at now; tail -f /dev/null
```

for getting a root shell. This command does give me a root shell but,

1. what does the first half of the command mean and how does it work?

Removing the tail command results in the shell closing instantly.

2. How does the tail command keep the shell open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command plan the launch of a command (`sudo at now`), the planned command is a shell which has your console as a standard input, standard output and standard error. The `$(tty)` is replaced here by something like `/dev/pty/0` which depends of your console. This is needed because the planned jobs are launched by a daemon without TTY redirection.

The `tail -f /dev/null` just wait forever (or a Ctrl-C) and avoid interaction with the TTY, and then between the shell from where you launch this command and the root shell. Without it, I guess that you have 2 shells in parallel which read your TTY and what you type could be interpreted randomly by one shell or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My mistake, i also wanted to know how the first  part of the command works. I edited the question to be more accurate. What i do not understand is the purpose and direction of each redirection operator. What i mean by that is, I know " /bin/sh <$(tty) " redirects the tty value to /bin/bash, but what about the other two operators? PS. I think u meant $(tty) instead of $(err)

Comment: When you log on a computer, there is a TTY which makes the link between your programs (shell, other interactive applications), and the way to display what they print. It can be a physical TTY (with a old physical terminal), or an emulated terminal (with Xterm, ssh…). You can get the name of the TTY with the command `tty`. The `at` command breaks the link between the future command and your TTY. If you want this future command to interact with the same TTY, you should explicit a redirection.

Comment: Ok,,, Now i understand its purpose. But  still have no clue about the direction in which value is exchanged in each redirection operator. I hope i am making my question clear to you.

Comment: `<$(tty)` is to send the TTY to the shell.  `>$(tty)` is to send the shell standard output to the TTY. `2>$(tty)` is to send the standard error of the shell to the TTY. `<` and `>` are nearly arrows graphically. Then the direction is easily remembered.

Comment: Thanks man. I read your answer along with this  [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138390) and now i kinda understand whats going on. Thanks again <3

Comment: One more doubt. The tail command helps keep the shell open. Why is the first command still running even when the tail -f is executed? Isn't the tail supposed to execute after the first command ?